# Add Crop Marks to PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file of user designed HTML that will then be send to a printing house for print and delivery. The printing house wish me to add crop marks on the .pdf.

I'm currently doing this with CSS by placing position: absolute; images over the design with the crop marks. However the Printing Software that the printing house is using can not "find" these Crop Marks.

I guess because I'm not doing it in the "official way".

Is there any functionality of creating crop marks with wkhtmltopdf? How do I make printers or other software understand that the images I included in the document is cropmarks and not just some normal image part of the content?

Answer (score 0):

How is the page's CropBox defined? Also you may check out the section 14.11.3 Printer’s Marks, of the PDF specification and find how you can get it working with your software.

from spec:
*The crop box defines the region to which the contents of the page shall be clipped (cropped) when displayed or printed. Unlike the other boxes, the crop box has no defined meaning in terms of physical page geometry or intended use; it merely imposes clipping on the page contents. However, in the absence of additional information (such as imposition instructions specified in a JDF or PJTF job ticket), the crop box determines how the page’s contents shall be positioned on the output medium. The default value is the page’s media box.*